# Why are my interval polling requests occurring only once?

Tags: angular, rxjs, bandwidth, angular-httpclient

I am trying to make a simple polling service using rxjs and angular 7 and am running into a recurring issue that my requests are only actually being fired once but the interval completes successfully with no errors.

My service component looks like this:

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { interval, Subject } from 'rxjs/index';
    import { exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

      constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ) {
      }

     getPing() {
        const req = new HttpRequest('GET', this.getUrl, {responseType: 'blob', headers: new HttpHeaders(), reportProgress: true});
            interval(1000)
              .pipe(take(4))
              .pipe(exhaustMap(()=> this.httpClient.request(req)))
              .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
     }
```

I have console logs showing that the interval occurs and completes after 4 intervals but only the first request is called according to the network tab.
If I use fetch instead of http client or change the interval to a loop the service behaves as expected however I would prefer to not use those approaches.  Does anybody know what I'm missing?

I am using angular 7.0.0 and rxjs 6.2.2
[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2uwa.png)    [Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNmQt.png)

Comment: How long does the network request take? `exhaustMap` ignores incoming notifications as long as the inner observable has not completed. try with `concatMap`

Comment: @ggradnig the requests should take about ~300ms. I have tried concatMap based on a similar threads recommendation however the output is the same.

Comment: is your first network request successful @Hunter ?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your error with your code. Please have a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzma1t

Comment: @ggradnig well crud lol.  I have just edited my original post to include screen shots of my console and network tab to illustrate whats happening but to answer your question the first request is completing successfully.

Comment: hm I'm a bit clueless about this. Probably has something to do with caching but I'm not quite sure. I can however assure you by your console output that four requests are sent via http client, they just don't seem to reach the network interface. do you have interceptors configured?

Comment: @ggradnig I thought it might be a caching issue either but I spun up an express server and set the cache control to not cache and have tried on all major browsers. As an aside part of why I don't want to use fetch is due to the lack of IE support.

Comment: @ggradnig   As far as the network interface, window.performance Timing Resources only show the first call as well. 
To your question about interceptors I do not.

Comment: @HunterJohnson Have you looked at the stackblitz that ggradnig provided? I ran it also and seemed to get valid results.

Comment: @DeborahK Have you just run the stackblitz or have you run locally? I ask because I agree that the stackblitz is valid but what I haven't been able to figure out is why locally (cross checked through all browsers and 3 machines) it only calls once or twice on occasion. My best guess is that this is some sort of hidden optimization in HttpClient that I have thus far been unable to disable. I am considering just changing my endpoint to post and posting a trivial identifier like a timestamp instead.

Comment: @Hunter I'm curious: have you found a solution or the cause of your issue?

Comment: @ggradnig Sort of. So what I was able to find out was that HttpClient seems to cache get requests occurring to the same request address.  I was not able to figure out how to disable this functionality but the work around that I made was to change to a post and trade a timestamp with the service. I suppose I could have also put a url param if I was deadset on keeping it a get. Simply using headers did not work.